# Automatically check date checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 checkboxes and 2 inputs.
The second checkbox is `parent()` of the 1 `input type number` and the third checkbox is `parent()` of the 2 `input type number`:

```
$calendar .= "<td bgcolor='$color' data-semana=''><font size='2px'/> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day' $marcado_data $disabled> <strong style='color:#5ca2df'>$year-$month-$day</strong> <br /> 
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div>
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço' $marcado_almoco $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' value='$marcado_almoco_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div></font></center></td>";}
```

To automatically mark the 2 and 3 `checkbox` by putting a value greater than zero in the `input type number` I have estre script:

```
<script> 
var inputs_ = document.querySelectorAll("[type='number'][name^='arrachar']"); 
for(var x=0; x<inputs_.length; x++){ 

inputs_[x].addEventListener("input", function(){ 

var box = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']"); 
box.checked = this.value > 0 ? true : false; 

}); 

}
</script>
```

when filling in the 1 or 2 `input type number`, in addition to automatically marking the `checkbox parent()` of it, I also want to automatically check the first `checkbox` of the date.
Is it possible to adapt my `script` to do this?

**The solution would be this by changing the script:**

```
<script> 
var inputs_ = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type='number'][name^='arrachar']")]; 
for(var x=0; x<inputs_.length; x++){ 
  inputs_[x].addEventListener("input", function(){ 
    var box = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']"); 

    box.checked = !getValuesLessorEqualZero([this]);

    var firstBox = document.getElementById('firstCB');
    firstBox.checked = this.value > 0 ? true : false;

    var valueAllLessOrZero = getValuesLessorEqualZero(inputs_);
    if(valueAllLessOrZero) firstBox.checked = false;
  }); 
}

const getValuesLessorEqualZero = (inputs) => {
  var lengthInputs = inputs.length;
  var valueLessOrZero = true;

  for(let i = 0; i < lengthInputs && valueLessOrZero; i++) {
    valueLessOrZero = inputs[i].value <= 0 ? true : false;
  }

  return valueLessOrZero;
};
</script>
```

But there is a problem, when I put a value greater than zero in an input, it automatically marks the checkbox of day one and not the date according to the input that I am filling. For example, I put value in the input of the day 2018-11-18 and select the checkbox of the date of the day 2018-11-01.
Image problem example:
[Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkYqF.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the first line valid? Can you format your code more clearly?

Comment: This line `$marcado_pequeno =$marcado_almoco ==$marcado_pequeno_qtd =$marcado_almoco_qtd=''` evaluates to `true`. And is a classic UB i think. Variable `$marcado_almoco` is undefined as far as i see. And anything can happen with undefined variables.

Comment: @Eugene Anisiutkin , this line was wrong, the correct one is like this `$marcado_pequeno =$marcado_almoco =$marcado_pequeno_qtd =$marcado_almoco_qtd='';`

Comment: @Bruno, the code still lacks several things. I see no post Form and no output of `$calendar` variable. Aslo the problem with the `$marcado_pequeno =$marcado_almoco =$marcado_pequeno_qtd =$marcado_almoco_qtd=''` changed, but is still there. Right now it always evaluates to an empty string.

Comment: @Eugene Anisiutkin, I already edited the question with the necessary code

Comment: @Bruno, I strongly will suggest to reformat the code. The formatting is very bad. For the sake of checking, i copied the code and it does not and will not work. It has missing brakets, and probably several other things. I will look into it in my spare time, but right now I will be honest - the code is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

First of all on the first line you wrote double equal:

```html
$marcado_pequeno =$marcado_almoco =$marcado_pequeno_qtd =$marcado_almoco_qtd='';
```

Second of all, it's quite unclear so if anything just remember that you need to put the input's in form tag's and get the information with "get" or "request" or "post" globals.

Lastly, for your issue.

```html
while ((the input) == 1){
   <script> 
    document.getElementById("checkbox id").checked = true
    </script>
}
```

Comment: You don't. The solution doesn't solve anything. It doesn't even fix the `$marcado_pequeno =$marcado_almoco =$marcado_pequeno_qtd =$marcado_almoco_qtd=''`, which right now always evaluates to an empty string

Comment: @Eugene Anisiutkin, but the code is working, it just does not checkbox the date automatically, the checkbox of each input, when it is filled with a value greater than zero is selected automatically